# How to use both gtag config and GTM GA4 configuration on the same measurement id (GA4 of course)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

We need to be able to allow website users to create custom analytics events in GTM and also push our standard application GA4 events through a gtag implementation. I'd like the GTM GA4 to remain the standard way since this will be done by non-tech users in these cases.

I know if you add them both the standard way you will double track events/user count/session count (new users will not be affected).

I'm trying to pinpoint the exact reason the double tracking is happening. Obviously, some of it could be the multiple analytics script on the same measurement id. We can handle preventing the on-site script and configure the gtag to not send page view.

My question is if we can call config on gtag for a measurement id and also have the GTM GA4 configuration for the same measurement id without issue. I'm unsure if that will also cause issues. Another option is to not call config through gtag and push the events through gtag and just use the GTM configuration. I'm also unsure if that's an option that would work properly.

Note: Do not need replies linking to the google documentation and told not to do it.

The current, apparent behavior of calling gtag config is that it checks if the analytics script is on the site yet and adds it if not. That would be fine in this case, as long as calling config doesn't do anything else (add another session id, etc).

Comment: From my experience, configs overwrite each other, so the last one wins, meaning any parameters set on previous configs do not get passed in events.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath i'm not too worried about the parameters passed in config since these are third party run analytics accounts. More just trying to find a way to prevent any duplicate user and event tracking. Preliminary testing seems to suggest not calling the gtag config and pushing the gtag events to the measurement id setup in GTM. I wasn't sure if that would work initially.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue is with the configuration being implemented in both GTM and via gtag config. Duplicate tracking is exacerbated by the "enhanced event measurement" enabled on the data stream, which tracks some default events. If that is turned on setting send page view to false in gtag will not work.

The fix was to not call gtag config at all and continue to push events through gtag. Of course, you may have to handle when your events start firing to wait for the gtag script from the GTM to load.